# Want to scrape highlights

Tags: css, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to scrape the Hot stat line from flashscore. In order to do this, I want to for example scrape the Hot stat of this page: https://www.flashscore.com/match/UZOxr6ME/#match-summary

Therefore I want to scrape:

```
<div class="previewLine"><b>Hot stat:</b> PL games refereed by Andy Madley this season 
have seen a 75% home win ratio.</div>.
```

Since there are on this page 6 lines with div class 'previewLine I am wording what the unique css path is for the hot stat line, or show this can be recognized.

I hope this question is clear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with xpath:

```
//div[@class="previewLine"][b[text()="Hot stat:"]]/text()
```

Find all div parents that has a class of "previewLine", and 'b' child with the text "Hot stat:".

Comment: Thank you for the comment. However, when I do this in scrapy shell, I get the following output: []

Comment: @error404 This site uses javaScript.

Comment: Ok thank you. How should i give this command to sublime text? For example; driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="previewLine"][b[text()="Hot stat:"]]/text()')